# Cannot connect to Postgres docker container from Django container

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, containers

```
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  backend:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_NAME=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    depends_on:
      - db
```

This is the docker config. The issue is backend(Django) is not able to connect to the postgres DB.
I tried with DB host as localhost and it was not able to connect.

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Then I changed host to the ip address of the db container but still no success, this time it was a timeout error.

```
could not connect to server: Connection timed out
Is the server running on host "172.11.0.2" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

This is how I'm connecting to postgres.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine("postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:postgres@172.11.0.2:5432/postgres",
                       poolclass=QueuePool,
                       pool_size=5,
                       max_overflow=10,
                       pool_timeout=1)
```

I think this has definitely something to do with the two containers being different but could someone help me on how to connect to Postgres container from Django's container?

Comment: `postgresql+psycopg2://psg:psg@db:5432/psg` should be your connection string. As soon as two containers are on the same docker network they can access themselves with their "short" names.

Comment: tried with this, getting `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known`.

Comment: @VK: Explicitly create a network and attach your containers to it, then check if they can find each other.

Comment: Instead of the ip 172.11.0.2, try the ip 0.0.0.0

Comment: @iepathos tried with that as well, got connection refused.

Answer (score 0):

> Any service can reach any other service at that service’s name.

In `docker-compose` services are exposed to each other by their name. So in the host you need to use `db` which is the name of database service.

[For more details check docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#links)